# How to put lines in the right way in a landscape without \hbox too wide?

Tags: tables, landscape

Why am I having no lines to go till the end of the landscape and how may I put these figures in a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{float} 
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}

  \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}
            \small
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let 'tabular*' determine whitespace
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{12}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
                \toprule
                    & \multicolumn{11}{c}{$\alpha$} \\
                \cmidrule{2-12}
                    $\beta$ & {0.1} & {0.2} & {0.3} & {0.4} & {0.5} & {0.6} & {0.7} & {0.8} & {0.9} & {1}\\ 
                \midrule
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                    0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0.0005 & 0.005 & 0.0205 & 0.0536 & 0.1142 & 0.2317 & 0.5637 & -0.0585 \\
                    0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.001 & 0.0108 & 0.043 & 0.11 & 0.231 & 0.4659 & 1.1294 & -0.1154 \\
                    0.3 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0018 & 0.018 & 0.0683 & 0.1703 & 0.3524 & 0.7043 & 1.6986 & -0.1694 \\
                    0.4 & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.0028 & 0.0264 & 0.0966 & 0.2351 & 0.4787 & 0.9477 & 2.2724 & -0.2197 \\
                    0.5 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0042 & 0.0364 & 0.1281 & 0.3043 & 0.6104 & 1.1964 & 2.8512 & -0.2658 \\
                    0.6 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0058 & 0.0479 & 0.1627 & 0.378 & 0.7473 & 1.4505 & 3.435 & -0.3074 \\
                    0.7 & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.0079 & 0.0611 & 0.2005 & 0.4563 & 0.8893 & 1.71 & 4.0238 & -0.3444 \\
                    0.8 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0103 & 0.0758 & 0.2416 & 0.5389 & 1.0364 & 1.9746 & 4.6177 & -0.377 \\
                    0.9 & 0 & 0.0002 & 0.0132 & 0.0924 & 0.2859 & 0.6257 & 1.1882 & 2.2442 & 5.2163 & -0.4053 \\
                    1 & 0.0001 & 0.0002 & 0.0165 & 0.1106 & 0.3333 & 0.7169 & 1.3449 & 2.5187 & 5.8196 & -0.4293 \\ \midrule
                    $\beta$ & {1.1} & {1.2} & {1.3} & {1.4} & {1.5} & {1.6} & {1.7} & {1.8} & {1.9} & {2}\\ 
                \midrule
                    0     & 0   & 0 & 0       & 0       & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
                    0.1   & -0.6806 & -0.3482 & -0.2287 & -0.1629 & -0.119  & -0.0864 & -0.0601 & -0.0379 & -0.0181 & 0 \\
                    0.2   & -1.3601 & -0.6955 & -0.4568 & -0.3255 & -0.2379 & -0.1725 & -0.1201 & -0.0757 & -0.0364 & 0 \\
                    0.3   & -2.0372 & -1.0414 & -0.6839 & -0.4874 & -0.3563 & -0.2586 & -0.1801 & -0.1136 & -0.0545 & 0 \\
                    0.4   & -2.7116 & -1.3852 & -0.9094 & -0.6484 & -0.4741 & -0.3442 & -0.2399 & -0.1514 & -0.0728 & 0 \\
                    0.5   & -3.3826 & -1.7262 & -1.1332 & -0.808  & -0.5913 & -0.4296 & -0.2996 & -0.1891 & -0.0909 & 0 \\
                    0.6   & -4.0499 & -2.0645 & -1.355  & -0.9663 & -0.7075 & -0.5143 & -0.3589 & -0.2268 & -0.109  & 0 \\
                    0.7   & -4.7133 & -2.3998 & -1.5743 & -1.1231 & -0.8227 & -0.5986 & -0.4181 & -0.2642 & -0.1272 & 0 \\
                    0.8   & -5.3729 & -2.7318 & -1.7914 & -1.2781 & -0.9369 & -0.6822 & -0.4769 & -0.3017 & -0.1453 & 0 \\
                    0.9   & -6.0288 & -3.0608 & -2.0059 & -1.4313 & -1.0498 & -0.7652 & -0.5355 & -0.3391 & -0.1634 & 0 \\
                    1 & -6.681  & -3.3868 & -2.2181 & -1.5828 & -1.1616 & -0.8474 & -0.5937 & -0.3764 & -0.1816 & 0 \\ 
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
            \captionsetup{font=small}
            \caption{The mode, $m_{1}$, of a nomalized stable distribution depending on the parameters $\alpha $ and $\beta$}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of spaces in numbers are wrong. Instead of `table-format=1.2]` it should be `table-format=-1.4`. Also you define one column more than they are used. After corrections of aforementioned I obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}
        \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % let 'tabular*' determine whitespace
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                 S[table-format=1.1]
                           *{10}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                                }
        \toprule
                      & \multicolumn{10}{c}{$\alpha$} \\
        \cmidrule{2-11}
            {$\beta$} & {0.1} & {0.2} & {0.3} & {0.4} & {0.5} & {0.6} & {0.7} & {0.8} & {0.9} & {1}\\
        \midrule
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0.0005 & 0.005 & 0.0205 & 0.0536 & 0.1142 & 0.2317 & 0.5637 & -0.0585 \\
            0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.001 & 0.0108 & 0.043 & 0.11 & 0.231 & 0.4659 & 1.1294 & -0.1154 \\
            0.3 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0018 & 0.018 & 0.0683 & 0.1703 & 0.3524 & 0.7043 & 1.6986 & -0.1694 \\
            0.4 & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.0028 & 0.0264 & 0.0966 & 0.2351 & 0.4787 & 0.9477 & 2.2724 & -0.2197 \\
            0.5 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0042 & 0.0364 & 0.1281 & 0.3043 & 0.6104 & 1.1964 & 2.8512 & -0.2658 \\
            0.6 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0058 & 0.0479 & 0.1627 & 0.378 & 0.7473 & 1.4505 & 3.435 & -0.3074 \\
            0.7 & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.0079 & 0.0611 & 0.2005 & 0.4563 & 0.8893 & 1.71 & 4.0238 & -0.3444 \\
            0.8 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.0103 & 0.0758 & 0.2416 & 0.5389 & 1.0364 & 1.9746 & 4.6177 & -0.377 \\
            0.9 & 0 & 0.0002 & 0.0132 & 0.0924 & 0.2859 & 0.6257 & 1.1882 & 2.2442 & 5.2163 & -0.4053 \\
            1 & 0.0001 & 0.0002 & 0.0165 & 0.1106 & 0.3333 & 0.7169 & 1.3449 & 2.5187 & 5.8196 & -0.4293 \\ \midrule
            $\beta$ & {1.1} & {1.2} & {1.3} & {1.4} & {1.5} & {1.6} & {1.7} & {1.8} & {1.9} & {2}\\
        \midrule
            0     & 0   & 0 & 0       & 0       & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
            0.1   & -0.6806 & -0.3482 & -0.2287 & -0.1629 & -0.119  & -0.0864 & -0.0601 & -0.0379 & -0.0181 & 0 \\
            0.2   & -1.3601 & -0.6955 & -0.4568 & -0.3255 & -0.2379 & -0.1725 & -0.1201 & -0.0757 & -0.0364 & 0 \\
            0.3   & -2.0372 & -1.0414 & -0.6839 & -0.4874 & -0.3563 & -0.2586 & -0.1801 & -0.1136 & -0.0545 & 0 \\
            0.4   & -2.7116 & -1.3852 & -0.9094 & -0.6484 & -0.4741 & -0.3442 & -0.2399 & -0.1514 & -0.0728 & 0 \\
            0.5   & -3.3826 & -1.7262 & -1.1332 & -0.808  & -0.5913 & -0.4296 & -0.2996 & -0.1891 & -0.0909 & 0 \\
            0.6   & -4.0499 & -2.0645 & -1.355  & -0.9663 & -0.7075 & -0.5143 & -0.3589 & -0.2268 & -0.109  & 0 \\
            0.7   & -4.7133 & -2.3998 & -1.5743 & -1.1231 & -0.8227 & -0.5986 & -0.4181 & -0.2642 & -0.1272 & 0 \\
            0.8   & -5.3729 & -2.7318 & -1.7914 & -1.2781 & -0.9369 & -0.6822 & -0.4769 & -0.3017 & -0.1453 & 0 \\
            0.9   & -6.0288 & -3.0608 & -2.0059 & -1.4313 & -1.0498 & -0.7652 & -0.5355 & -0.3391 & -0.1634 & 0 \\
            1 & -6.681  & -3.3868 & -2.2181 & -1.5828 & -1.1616 & -0.8474 & -0.5937 & -0.3764 & -0.1816 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
            \captionsetup{font=small}
            \caption{The mode, $m_{1}$, of a nomalized stable distribution depending on the parameters $\alpha $ and $\beta$}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```